# Set header width dynamically base on column width

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I created a gridview with a floating header that stays in place when I scroll, however the gridview is generated dynamically with the header and columns auto-fitting the content.  Because the header is floating separately from the content its width is not the same as the columns in the gridview and because it is generated dynamically I don't want to assign a predefined width.  I am trying to get the width of every column in the first row in the gridview through c# and set the header width of each column to match that.  Right now I am trying:

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="Grid" ID="gv" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gridViewDataBind">
```

with c#

```
    protected void gridViewDataBind(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < e.Row.Cells.Count; c++)
    {
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            int maxWidth = 0;
            //iterate through each cell in the row
            //this loop will search for the widest cell
            if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Length > maxWidth)
            {
                maxWidth = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Length;
                //update the header cell to match the maxWidth found
                //I multiplied by 10 to give it some length
                Unit u_maxWidth = Unit.Parse((maxWidth * 16).ToString());
                gv.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Width = u_maxWidth;
                e.Row.Cells[i].Width = u_maxWidth;
            }
            if ((gv.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text.Length) > maxWidth)
            {
                maxWidth = gv.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text.Length;
                //update the header cell to match the maxWidth found
                //I multiplied by 10 to give it some length
                Unit u_maxWidth = Unit.Parse((maxWidth * 16).ToString());
                gv.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Width = u_maxWidth;
                gv.Columns[i].ItemStyle.Width = u_maxWidth;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is now setting the widths, however setting the cell width is not giving me the results I am looking for.  When I try to set column width I get an error that it is larger than the collection since no other columns have a width.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Since we can't get the unit width, lets force it.  We know data is coming in and have a length of that data. Depending on your font-family being used, you could manipulate it that way. I used sample data from 2 objects.

Move the int maxWidth outside the RowDataBound event into the class scope, otherwise it'll reset eachtime a row is populated.

```
private int maxWidth = 0;
```

Update the DataRow conditional statement as follows:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    log.Debug("Found a datarow");

    for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        log.Debug(String.Format("Row.Cell length : {0} || maxWidth : {1}", e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Length, maxWidth));

        //iterate through each cell in the row
        //this loop will search for the widest cell
        if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Length > maxWidth)
        {
            maxWidth = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Length;
            log.Debug(String.Format("maxWidth is now : {0}", maxWidth));

            //update the header cell to match the maxWidth found
            //I multiplied by 10 to give it some length
            Unit u_maxWidth = Unit.Parse((maxWidth * fontFamilyFactor).ToString());

            log.Debug(String.Format("u_maxWidth is now : {0}", u_maxWidth));
            gv.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Width = u_maxWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using log4net as my debugger. Here's the output from my log file with the sample data I ran:

```
Found a datarow
Row.Cell length : 0 || maxWidth : 0
Row.Cell length : 7 || maxWidth : 0
maxWidth is now : 7
u_maxWidth is now : 70px
Row.Cell length : 13 || maxWidth : 7
maxWidth is now : 13
u_maxWidth is now : 130px
Row.Cell length : 0 || maxWidth : 13
Row.Cell length : 12 || maxWidth : 13
Row.Cell length : 0 || maxWidth : 13

Found a datarow
Row.Cell length : 0 || maxWidth : 13
Row.Cell length : 3 || maxWidth : 13
Row.Cell length : 13 || maxWidth : 13
Row.Cell length : 0 || maxWidth : 13
Row.Cell length : 12 || maxWidth : 13
Row.Cell length : 0 || maxWidth : 13
Row.Cell length : 0 || maxWidth : 13
```

Comment: Thanks but I still have this issue.  The gv vs gv_YourSite was a typo on my part, they are the same gridview.  I have doing this after the gridview is databound and rendered so it shouldn't be the issue seen in the related article.  I have updated the original post with the new code.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I am not experienced with c# and don't have a debugger configured, however with the new setup and watching it debug the cell widths are now set.  However setting the cell length is getting inconsistent and results.  I believe I want to set gv_YourSite.Columns[i].ItemStyle.Width instead, however when I try I receive the error 
"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."
I'm now trying to set the column widths to a size that the new width isn't larger than the collection since they will be re-sized with the method.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I found is that because auto-generate columns had to be on, the columns were generating with "width" being empty and autofitting to the content of the cells.  I cannot fill in the width because it would be wider than the table which has no width until rendering.  Since I could not call a method automatically after rendering the table I could not use the method to apply the width.

Ultimately I used literal control to generate the same table as an HTML table and assigned the width based on the number of characters in the cells.